# How to show that the convergence of a positive definite function to zero implies that the variable converges to zero

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

I think it's obvious but I cannot show it explicitly.

If a function $f$ is continuous and positive definite, that is, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all nonzero $x$.

Then, how to show that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x_t) = 0 \implies \lim_{t \to \infty}x_t = 0$?

Comment: This looks wrong. Consider $f(x):=x^2\exp(-x)$ and $x_t:=t$.

Answer (score 1):

The result is false. Think of $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{1+x^4}$. You have that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n) = 0,
$$

but $\lim_{n\to \infty} n \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also wrong when $f$ is radially unbounded?

Comment: It does not need to be unbounded, it is just required that $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x) \ne 0$.

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? I can guess the condition you suggested works fine intuitively but I cannot prove it in a rigorous way.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, it holds that $\lim f(x_n)= f(\lim x_n)$. So, if the sequence converges to a finite value, say $\lim x_n = L$, you have that $\ lim f(x_n) = 0$ , which in turn implies that $f(L) = 0$ and, therefore, that $L=0$. However, if $L=\pm \infty$ the limit can be zero when $\lim_{x\to L}f(x) = 0$.

Comment: But there is no guarantee that $\lim x_n$ exists.