# How to show that the convergence of a positive definite radially unbounded function to zero implies that the variable converges to zero

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, continuity

This is based on [the previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416211/how-to-show-that-the-convergence-of-a-positive-definite-function-to-zero-implies).

If a function $f$ is continuous, positive definite, that is, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for all nonzero $x$. Also, in this case, $\textit{f is radially unbounded}$.

Then, is it true that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x_t) = 0 \implies \lim_{t \to \infty}x_t = 0$?

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it for a while, I suppose that it is true.
If the following proof is incorrect, please let me know.

Proposition: Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, positive definite, and radially unbounded.
$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x_{t}) = 0$ implies that $\lim_{t \to \infty} x_t = 0$.

Proof)
Let $B_{a} := B(0, a)$ (a ball with radius of $a >0$).
Let $f(X) := \{ y \in \mathbb{R} | y = f(x) \text{ for some } x \in X\}$, and $f^{-1}(Y) := \{ x \in X| f(x) = y \text{ for some } y \in Y \}$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$.
Since $f$ is radially unbounded, there exists $r' > 0$ such that $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}) \subset B_{r'}$, which implies that $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon})$ is bounded.
Since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon})$ is closed.
These imply that $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon})$ is compact.

By extreme value theorem, $x \mapsto \lVert x \rVert$ has the minimum of $r > 0$ over $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon})$.

Note that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(x_t)= 0 \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists T \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $t \geq T$, $f(x_t) \leq \epsilon \implies \lVert x_t \rVert \leq r, \forall t \geq T$.
As $r \to 0 $ as $\epsilon \to 0$,
this concludes the proof.

EDIT: one might wonder $r \to 0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. For a similar statement, please see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4416903/how-to-show-that-the-maximum-value-of-a-given-continuous-function-over-epsilon-b/4416946#4416946).

EDIT2: I realised that the proof holds true without $\delta$.