# How to show that the maximum value of a given continuous function over epsilon ball is continuous

Tags: continuity, monotone-functions

I'd like to show that the following statement:

Suppose that a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is given.
Let $B_{\epsilon}$ be a ball at the origin with the radius of $\epsilon \geq 0$ ($B_{0} := \{ 0 \}$).

As $B_{\epsilon}$ is compact, it is indeed that the maximum of $f$ over the ball exists as
$g(\epsilon) := \max_{x \in B_{\epsilon}}f(x)$.

It is trivial that $g(0) = 0$ and $g$ is monotonically increasing.
How can one show that $g$ is continuous, and the image of $g$ is $[0, \infty)$ in a rigorous way?

EDIT: $f$ is positive definite as well, i.e., $f(0) = 0$ and $f(x) > 0$ for any nonzero $x$.

Comment: You could use that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous. Thus, if you make the ball slightly bigger, the maximum can also get slightly bigger. Can you make this rigorous?

Comment: Also the image will only be $[0;\infty)$ if $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: For the latter comment: Oh, you're right. Thanks :)

Comment: For the former one: I'll take a look at it after a while. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ah, I got it. Every newly added point by enlarging the ball as the amount of delta would provide that the maximum can only change up to epsilon by uniform continuity, which concludes the proof considering the definition of continuity. Is it right?

Comment: That is absolutely correct :)

Answer (score 1):

@SeverinSchraven How about this? Do you think that this is correct?

pf) Fix $r \geq 0$. For any $\delta' > 0$, $B_{r + \delta'}$ is compact $\implies$ $f$ is uniformly continuous on $B_{r + \delta'}$. Note that the fact that $f$ is continuous on a compact space implies $f$ is uniformly continuous on the same space can be driven by finite open cover argument. Therefore, it can be used to prove the proposition of interest.

Then, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\lvert \delta \rvert < \min(\delta', r)$ implies $g(r+\delta) - g(r) \leq \epsilon$.
This holds true for all $r \geq 0$, which implies $g$ is continuous.

Note:
If $f$ is uniformly bounded, i.e., for all $x$, $\lvert f(x) \rvert \leq M$ for some $M > 0$, then there exists $a \in (0, M]$ such that $g:[0, \infty) \to [0, a)$.
if $f$ is unbounded, $a = \infty$.

Comment: You might also want to add $0\leq g(r+\delta)-g(r)$ (as we take the maximum over a larger set, hence $g(r)\leq g(r+\delta)$). This way we can conclude $\vert g(r+\delta)-g(r)\vert \leq \varepsilon$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes, I omitted it. Thank you for your suggestion :)